# Regular Expression- have different digits

Tags: regex

How I use regular expression in order to check if my number have different digits. 
For example: the number: 5554 is ok but the number: 5555 is not ok.

Comment: And how many numbers are there? Millions? Thousands? 10?

Comment: Could you refine your requirements please? For example, is it just the last digit, or do you require "at least n different digits"?

Answer (score 3):

This regex checks if all the digits are the same. Then take the opposite and you will find if your number has different digits.

```
^(\d)\1*$
```

This regex checks if at least one digit is different:

```
(\d)((?!\1)\d)+
```

**EDIT** in C# with RegularExpression Attribute

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\d)((?!\1)\d)+")]
```

Comment: @Hadas It depends on the language you are using.

Comment: What is the diffrence?
I use C#.

Comment: @Hadas Then you just have to test if the number match the regular expression and if not, your number has at least one different number.

Comment: Thanks but I use the regular expression in the RegulaeExpressionAttribute of property.

Comment: @Hadas Post Edited for your solution

Comment: @Hadas If this answer fit to your problem then please accept the response

Comment: `^(\d)((?!\1)\d)+$` does not match 5554, it only checks whether the first number does not occur anywhere else in the string.

Comment: I find a new problem: I want I can put this chars "()+-.* " into the number. any solution?

Comment: Then replace all occurences of \d by [\d()+-.* ] in your expression.
If it works pls accept the response...

Comment: but I dont want I can put more a single char. for example:
"12-34" is ok
"12--34" is not ok

Comment: What do you want to do exactly???? I'll not waste my time trying to understand what you are looking for...

Comment: I want to write regular expression for phones but I can use it in every country (According Plimus validation).that's all.and in phone number you can't put two special chars one after second.

Comment: But why number have to be different?

Comment: I dont know number with one digit.We have different digits in our numbers. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In *perl* for any digits:

```
/^(\d)\1*$/
```

Some tests:

Content of *script.pl*:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
        print unless /^(\d)\1*$/;
}

__DATA__
55555
56
5556
56565
5
6555
55655
55
```

Running the script in a linux machine:

```
perl script.pl
```

Result:

```
56
5556
56565
6555
55655
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Four digits which are not the same:

```
([0-9])(?!\1\1\1)[0-9]{3}
```

Backreferences in a negative lookahead don't work in some regex implementations. I tried this regex with `grep -P`.

Comment: We can write: ([0-9])(?!\1{3})[0-9]{3} 
Becouse if we want a long number we don't want to write "\1" million times...

Comment: I find a new problem: I want I can put this chars "()+-.* " into the number. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There could come a day when someone wants a Regular Expression solution
to finding at least ***n*** different digits in a string of numbers.

The *N* is 3 in this case to match the sample provided.

This regex is a template, the bottom part repeats in a way where
each step requires finding a different number. Hence like *`(?! \1 )`* ,,,
*`(?! \1 | \2 )`*   ,,,  *`(?! \1 | \2 | \3 )`* and so on.

```
(\d)(?:\d*?(?!\1)(\d)(?:\d*?(?!\1|\2)(\d)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/kyqEwe/1

```
( \d )                      # (1)
(?:
   \d*? 
   (?! \1 )
   ( \d )                   # (2)
   (?:
      \d*? 
      (?! \1 | \2 )
      ( \d )                # (3)
   )
)
```

A slightly more efficient version can be pared down to this:

```
(\d)\d*?(?!\1)(\d)\d*?(?!\1|\2)\d
```

https://regex101.com/r/b36MfA/1

```
( \d )                # (1)

\d*? 
(?! \1 )
( \d )                # (2)

\d*? 
(?! \1 | \2 )
\d
```

Note that for statistics, capture *all* the distinct numbers.

Comment: Plus one for an answer to a question that has been posted a decade ago :-)

Comment: @Jan I have served. I will be of service. John Wick

Answer (score 0):

```
        var a = 5555;
        var b = 5554;
        var a1 = a.ToString().ToCharArray().Distinct().Count();
        var b1 = b.ToString().ToCharArray().Distinct().Count();
```

And then check for count.