# Regular Expression - have at least n different digits

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I want to use regular expression to check if the numbers have more than 2 different digits. For example, AB1000002 is allowed but AB1000000 is not allowed.

My question is similar to this one but seems to be more complicated.
Reference: [Regular Expression- have different digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398516/regular-expression-have-different-digits)

Thanks in advance!

---

I am not good at coding, I have tried to fix this problem but what I can do is just simply make the check of "at least 1 different digit" start from the second number...which is a bit stupid sorry I know...
`\d(\d)((?!\1)\d)+`

Comment: please make an attempt and share it before asking for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression- have different digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398516/regular-expression-have-different-digits)

Comment: the other question is the answer to this one, just add AB or `\w+` after `^`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but something like `^(?=.*(\d).*\1).*(?!\1)(\d).*\2.*` might help.

Comment: Sounds like e.g. [`(\d)(?=.*?(?!\1)(\d)).*(?!\2|\1)\d`](https://regex101.com/r/XOMgeV/1) though this might get difficult to maintain if demands change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why to use regular expressions when the set() does it easy and efficiently?

```
for st in ["AB1000002",  "AB1000000"]:
    if len(set(st[2:])) > 2: # remove AB and run set on numbers
        print(st)

AB1000002
```

Comment: omg, i didn't think in this way. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not a Python person but it appears that another way would be `...
if len("".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(st)) > 2 ...`, which must be preceded by  `from collections import OrderedDict`. One disadvantage of both approaches is that all the unique characters must be determined, which could only be a problem if the string is really long. By contrast, using a regex, as @sln as done, stops once three unique characters have been found.

Answer (score 2):

There could come a day when someone wants a Regular Expression solution
to finding at least ***n*** different digits in a string of numbers.

The *N* is 3 in this case to match the sample provided.

This regex is a template, the bottom part repeats in a way where
each step requires finding a different number. Hence like *`(?! \1 )`* ,,,
*`(?! \1 | \2 )`*   ,,,  *`(?! \1 | \2 | \3 )`* and so on.

https://regex101.com/r/kyqEwe/1

```
(\d)(?:\d*?(?!\1)(\d)(?:\d*?(?!\1|\2)(\d)))
```

or

```
(\d)\d*?(?!\1)(\d)\d*?(?!\1|\2)\d
```

https://regex101.com/r/b36MfA/1

```
( \d )                # (1)

\d*? 
(?! \1 )
( \d )                # (2)

\d*? 
(?! \1 | \2 )
\d
```

Comment: You might note that `?` in each `\d*?` term is not needed, but may improve efficiency, and also mention @booblebubble's suggested regex in a comment on the question. I did a brief test of all three--just looking at number of steps performed for the same data set at regex101.com--and the results were not definitive. Also, the third capture group, `( \d )`, can be replaced with just `\d` if there is no interest in the value of that digit. There can be multiple matches, of course. If only a single match is desired one can tack `.*` on to the end.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Thanks. Yeah I removed the cluster syntax, and the last capture group. which reduced the steps. And I'm not a big fan of _`\d*`_ greed for these as matching the endless possibility is just _wrong_. `.*` is ok in assertions though, imo.